# How can I play a private 5v5 de_dust game with my friends in the new CSGO version?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Before you had play with friends and could do private 5v5 matches easily
how do we do it in the new version?
I want to do a private 5v5 de_dust, generic game.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaking, you have to create a game with no bots, and just add your friends through the Steam overlay.

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, you can invite your friends to a lobby and play `offline with bots`.
Another alternative that is popular is to use services such as [popflash](https://popflash.site/). You can also use hubs on [faceit](https://www.faceit.com/).